# Angular Translate HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, angular-translate

I know this has been asked here before but none of the answers seem to work for my case

I bought this theme [Angle](https://wrapbootstrap.com/theme/angle-bootstrap-admin-app-angularjs-WB04HF123) which is working with Angular 1.4.2 and Angular translate 2.6.0 (even updated to last 2.7.2)

The template by default has the Translate module on it

This is the config file

```
  $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
      prefix : 'app/i18n/',
      suffix : '.json'
  });
  $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('es');
  $translateProvider.useLocalStorage();
  $translateProvider.usePostCompiling(true);
   // Enable escaping of HTML
  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize'); // I added this line based on Docs wasn't before
```

And the translation files in JSON format

```
  {
   "page": {
    "PAGES_WELCOME" : "Welcome to <br> MY APPLICATION, HEY THERE IS A BR TAG BEFORE ME"
  },

  "login": {
    .
    .
    .
    .
  },
```

But i cannot add HTML tags inside the text, on the JSON file, instead of getting

**Welcome to
MY APP**

I'm getting

**Welcome to < br > MY APP**

How can i fix this?

**EDIT**

I do NOT want to remove the tags, my JSON file is modified by the backend, and it can and will contain HTML Tags, i want those tags to work on the output.

**JADE Example Where the content is binding**

```
div(class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12 footer-left")
  p(class="text-center") 
    {{ 'page.PAGES_WELCOME' | translate }}
```

Comment: Would you please provide the html where you are binding this content?

Comment: Sure, i'm using Jade and gulp compiles to HTML

Comment: I suspect you would probably want to use something like `ng-bind-html` which lives inside of the `angular-sanitize` package. I am trying to understand the intent of this question. Would you check this plunkr our and see if this is something you're trying to do? (http://plnkr.co/edit/qLJL2Gu1tjzWuf5Rz8dy?p=preview)

Comment: It's related to [Angular Translate](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) 

Not sure what do i have to see on the plunkr but it's not related

Comment: Fair enough then; thanks for the clarification. (Also you would just need to hit start if it didn't do it by default)

Comment: @Matt thank you for your approach

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Angular sanitizes any html strings during its interpolation.
In order to get around this you will need to mark the HTML as safe in $sce before injecting. Then also use ngBindHtml to output the html.

I've not used angular-translate before, but this may work:

```
//app is the main module
app.filter("htmlSafe", ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return function(htmlCode){
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlCode);
    };
}]);

//then to output it
<span data-ng-bind-html="'page.PAGES_WELCOME' | translate | htmlSafe"></span>
```

Comment: Had another function to make it HTML Safe but the `ng-bind-html` did the trick, thanks!

Comment: Only having `ng-bind-html` (without `htmlSafe` filter) did the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: The answer of @AElMehdi is short and efficient, I vote for @AElMehdi!

Comment: @AliBenMessaoud this question was posted 6 years ago, I doubt I could wait 4 years for his answer to pop-up

Answer (score 17):

You can keep your `JSON` file as it is, and then simply use the `innerHTML` attribute in the `HTML` to render your text like so:

```
 <div [innerHTML]="'page.PAGES_WELCOME' | translate"></div>
```

Comment: This worked for me. I think this is the most recent (at time of writing) way of binding to the innerHTML and side-stepping the HTML escaping that Angular's templating provides by default.

Comment: This won't let you access css classes unless you set view encapsulation to none

Answer (score 2):

Tested with AngularJS 1.4.7, I just use this:

```
<span data-ng-bind-html="'my.i18n.code.to.translate.html.tags' | translate"></span>
```

Since I do not want to inject any filter but above is just worked on my own trusted i18n string. Of course, the accepted answer would be more safe but this one is just work right away.

Answer (score 2):

Install ngSanitize module.

It makes you able to bind html content, then change your code like this:

```
ng-bind-html="'a_key_with_html' | translate"
```

Answer (score 1):

> But i cannot add HTML tags inside the text, on the JSON file, instead of getting
>
> **Welcome to MY APP**
>
> I'm getting
>
> **Welcome to**
>
> **MY APP**

You have a `<br>` which is breaking the line like you said you do not want so remove it like so:

```
{
   "page": {
    "PAGES_WELCOME" : "Welcome to {{appName}}"
  },

  "login": {
    .
    .
    .
    .
  },
```

Comment: This is not what i'm asking for, i want the line to break but angular is printing <br> within the line.

Comment: @DannyG - Yes you are not asking it now because you just changed your question :) You are going to have to show where the PAGES_WELCOME variable is called for us to be able to know.

Comment: I didn't changed the question, the <br> Tag was being interpreted by the editor and added the line break, i just wanted to show the output, PAGES_WELCOME is irrelevant, just for the example purpose.
It could be a single string without vars and still the HTML tags get printed on the screen

Comment: @DannyG - it is completely relevant how you are displaying the string to be able to explain why it is not allowing the <br>. My hunch is your added sanitization is stripping any code from strings that can be altered to prevent malicious inserts but that is a hunch - I can tell you for sure if you show the code necessary.

Comment: at first the sanitize service wasn't (I added it after reading the docs) and it wasn't working back there either.

Answer (score 1):

I actually really don't want  to use the tags in my html template. The tags isn't meaningful.

I finally got it to work. Environment: Angular 1.5.8, angular-tranlsate: 2.11.0

My solution is:
1. load ngSanitize and init the module

2. `$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('sanitize');`
3. `<p ng-bind-html="'Please <strong>refresh</strong> the browser' | translate"></p>`